# Add custom user property to page view

Tags: google-analytics

When users log into my website, they have a company that they are assigned to.

I can pass this value to the Data Layer as 'company'.

How do I get Analytics to include that in the page views event?

Answer (score 1):

First, you make a DL variable in GTM.

Next you use it in your pageview tag like so:

[image]

Next you go to your GA4 account where this traffic is flowing to and there you make a user-scoped custom dimension, connecting the user property to the custom dimension in the process.

That's it.